# Jest do not see TypeScript classes

Tags: typescript, jestjs

How to setup Jest to see my TypeScript classes placed in different files without import/export of those classes? I have bunch of TS classes in separate files. I ***can not*** use "import" or "export" of those classes (because of the JS interpreter which we use by company policy).

So I can not write:

```
export class MyClass {

}
```

and then use it in my tests like it is proposed:

```
import {MyClass} from "../MyClass"

test("MyClass test", () =} {
    let mc = new MyClass()
    // ...
})
```

Is there a way to explain Jest where to look for classes? Because TypeScript itself works well and compiles all of those classes and sees them.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by company policy?  How can you not use import / export in your tests?  Are your tests not written in typescript as well?  Are you running your code through the typescript compiler?

Jest only understands javascript, so you have to get your typescript to javascript using the typescript compiler (tsc). There is a node module [`ts-jest`](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/install) that does this.